# Need help to make audit trail using ATK Framework

Tags: php

I don't have any experience using ATK, If some one could help to giving me the tutorial page to make the Audit trail using ATK framework.  Thank you.

Comment: Hey @syida - No luck with the [ATK Framework wiki](http://www.atk-framework.com/wiki/ATK)?

Comment: @miku - yup unfortunately no luck

Comment: what kind of an audit trail are you looking for?  are we talking revision history, or access history, or both?

Comment: @nathan gonzalez - both (revision history, or access history). Can u help

Answer (score 0):

check out the atkEventLog class.  you would use it like this :

```
$this->addListener(atknew("atk.utils.atkeventlog"));
```

where $this is your node that you want an audit log for.  it requires a table called `atkeventlog`, but i can't remember if that is created by default or not...  anyway, check atk/utils/class.atkeventlog.inc for structure if needed.  i doubt this will do all of your revision history.  i seem to remember it being more of an access history.  you might see `user1 changed record 2 in SuperSecureArea` or something like that, but i don't think it will record field level changes.

for that you need to implement some of your own stuff, probably center around the `NF_TRACK_CHANGES` node flag.  this will pass the old values to `postUpdate` as `$rec[atkorgrec]`.  if i think about it i might post an implementation of this that i did a while back.